# Theories for electronic transport calculations

Tags: siesta, electronic-transport

Both software I know that do electronic transport calculations ([TranSIESTA](https://departments.icmab.es/leem/siesta/About/overview.html) and [QuantumATK](https://www.synopsys.com/silicon/quantumatk/resources/feature-list.html#negf)) , use Non-equilibrium Green's function (NEGF) method.

Are there other theoretical methods that can be used to calculate electronic transport properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tools for electronic transport calculations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/tools-for-electronic-transport-calculations)

Comment: Hi @CodyAldaz. Not exactly. In that question I ask for tools (independent of theory used). In this one, I am asking for theories other than non-equilibrium Green's function.

Comment: Does Boltzmann transport count? Codes like Boltztrap uses that but classical

Comment: @Thomas maybe you can answer. Classical is fine. Doesn't have to be quantum.

Answer (score 6):

## Boltzmann Transport

Transport of electrons in the presence of electric field and magnetic field can be described uisng [Boltzmann transport equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation). There are Classical and semi-classical formalisms and a detailed analysis can be found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128171035000116).

Codes like [BoltzTrap2](https://www.imc.tuwien.ac.at/forschungsbereich_theoretische_chemie/forschungsgruppen/prof_dr_gkh_madsen_theoretical_materials_chemistry/boltztrap2/), [BoltzWann](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010465513003160), [LanTrap](https://nanohub.org/groups/needs/lantrap) etc. have implemented BTE and can be used to study thermoelectric and electronic transport in materials.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the plane-wave codes can utilise a form of the wave-function matching technique to calculate device modes coupled to scattering states in the bulk parts, see e.g. http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.74.245404.